# How Information Gain Works in Text Classification

Tags: text, text-classification, information-theory

I have to learn information gain for feature selection right now, 
But I don't have clear comprehension about it. I am a newbie, and I'm confused about it.

How to use IG in feature selection (manual calculation)?

I just have clue this .. That have anyone can help me how to use the formula:

[image]

then this is the example:

[image]

Comment: please explain what you do and do not understand (the formula? the purpose of information gain? how to code it? what's a probability?)

Comment: i hope my explanation will help you.

Comment: It is a good question. Also, I have a related question about Information Gain, too. In some cases we need to calculate logarithm (0) which is not feasible to calculate. How we must do in such situations?

Answer (score 2):

> How to use information gain in feature selection?

Information gain (`InfoGain(t)`) measures the number of bits of information obtained for prediction of a class (c) by knowing the presence or absence of a term (t) in a document.

Concisely, **the information gain is a measure of the reduction in entropy of the class variable after the value for the feature is observed**. In other words, information gain for classification is a measure of how common a feature is in a particular class compared to how common it is in all other classes.

In text classification, feature means the terms appeared in documents (a.k.a corpus). Consider, two terms in the corpus - `term1` and `term2`. If `term1` is reducing entropy of the class variable by a larger value than `term2`, then `term1` is more useful than `term2` for document classification in this example.

**Example in the context of sentiment classification**

A word that occurs primarily in positive movie reviews and rarely in negative reviews contains high information. For example, the presence of the word “magnificent” in a movie review is a strong indicator that the review is positive. That makes “magnificent” a high informative word.

> Compute entropy and information gain in python

- [Measuring Entropy and Information Gain](https://mariuszprzydatek.com/2014/10/31/measuring-entropy-data-disorder-and-information-gain/)

Answer (score 0):

The formula comes from mutual information, in this case, you can think of mutual information as how much information the presence of the term t gives us for guessing the class.

[image]

Check: https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/mutual-information-1.html